# Filter Record and insert row by array of ids in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcCustomOrderHoursTaskLog]( @WorkLogIds nvarchar(MAX) = null, --a list of worklog IDs (comma-separated list). e.g. 1,2,3 @BatchId int = 0 )
```

I have a table `CustomOrderHoursTaskLog` in which I have a column WorkLogId.

The stored procedure needs to filter the @WorkLogIds. From the array of @WorkLogIds, if a given id is in `CustomOrderHoursTaskLog` table, then it has to do nothing.

But if the id is not exit in `CustomOrderHoursTaskLog` table, then it has to insert a row into the `CustomOrderHoursTaskLog` table. I want to check all the @WorkLogIds one by one in `CustomOrderHoursTaskLog` table. What i have to do. May be a loop. Please help me

Comment: And where is a problem? I don't see any description of obstacles that you have faced.

Comment: @cassandradied i have edited question. Please check it. lets see now can u help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be more specific, but if I got what you want:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE INSERT_EMPLOYEES
    @INIT_ID INT,
    @END_ID  INT

    AS
    BEGIN

        CREATE TABLE #ARRAY (ID INT)

        WHILE @INIT_ID <= @END_ID
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #ARRAY VALUES(@INIT_ID)
            SET @INIT_ID = @INIT_ID + 1
        END

        INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE 
        SELECT ID FROM #ARRAY A
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID = A.ID)

    END
```

then to execute it (example):

```
    EXEC INSERT_EMPLOYEES 1, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcCustomOrderHoursTaskLog](
@WorkLogIds nvarchar(MAX) = null,   --a list of worklog IDs (comma-separated list). e.g. 1,2,3
@BatchId int = 0
)
```

AS
BEGIN
--filter by worklog IDs

```
SET @WorkLogIds = isnull(@WorkLogIds, '')   
    CREATE TABLE #FilteredWorkLogIds
    (
        WorkLogId int not null
    )
    INSERT INTO #FilteredWorkLogIds (WorkLogId)
    SELECT CAST(data as int) FROM [nop_splitstring_to_table](@WorkLogIds, ',')  
    DECLARE @WorkLogIdsCount int    
    SET @WorkLogIdsCount = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #FilteredWorkLogIds)
INSERT INTO CustomOrderHoursTaskLog (WorkLogId, CustomOrderId, IsOrderGenerated, CreatedOnUtc, GeneratedOnUtc, BatchId)
SELECT WorkLogId, 0, 0, getdate(), null, @BatchId FROM #FilteredWorkLogIds W
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CustomOrderHoursTaskLog WHERE WorkLogId = W.WorkLogId)
DROP TABLE #FilteredWorkLogIds
```

End